# Can't use if statement in forfiles

Tags: cmd

Im trying to rename images in folder by their modify date-time.

```
@Echo On
forfiles /M *.jpg /C "cmd /c set "f=@fdate@ftime" & call rename @file %%f:~6,4%%.%%f:~3,2%%.%%f:~0,2%%[%%f:~10,2%%-%%f:~13,2%%-%%f:~16,2%%].jpg"
pause
```

but it if ftime hour is 1digit, it crews

2015.12.12[20-07-06].jpg

2015.12.16[3:-6:-8 ].jpg

So i wont to check, if 12th symbol in f is ":" (which is if hours are 2digit) or not, to correct positins. But

```
forfiles /M *.jpg /C "cmd /c set "f=@fdate@ftime" & call set b=%%f:~12,1%% & if %%b%%==":" (call "foo")"
```

dont work. I think its because i cant do "call if" and b is parsed earlier then calculated. What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In next code examples, `forfiles /M *.jpg` command part is replaced by ellipsis (`…`) for better readability:

You need either to use enabled delayed expansion (note `/V:ON` switch):

```
… /C "cmd /V:ON /c set "f=@fdate@ftime"& set "b=!f:~12,1!"& if [!b!]==[:] (call "foo")"
```

or to reformulate your test as follows:

```
… /C "cmd /c set "f=@fdate@ftime" & call set "b=%%f:~12,1%%"& call set "b=%%b::=%%"& if not defined b (call "foo")"
```

If delayed expansion is enabled already, then the former case should be with escaped `!` (exclamation mark) as follows:

```
… /C "cmd /V:ON /c set f=@fdate@ftime& set b=^!f:~12,1^!& if [^!b^!]==[:] (call "foo")"
```

**EDIT**: An operational example (note no inner `"` double quotes and no spaces before all `&` ampersand in next version)

```
echo OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
forfiles /M *.jpg /C "cmd /V:ON /c set f=@fdate@ftime& set b=!f:~12,1!& if [!b!]==[:] (echo(!f! !b! 13th) else (echo(!f! !b! not 13th)"
ENDLOCAL
pause >NUL
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
forfiles /M *.jpg /C "cmd /V:ON /c set f=@fdate@ftime& set b=^!f:~12,1^!& if [^!b^!]==[:] (echo ^!f^! ^!b^! 13th) else (echo ^!f^! ^!b^! not 13th)"
ENDLOCAL
pause >NUL
forfiles /M *.jpg /C "cmd /c set f=@fdate@ftime& call set b=%%f:~12,1%%& call set a=%%b::=%%& if not defined a (call echo %%f%% %%b%% 13th) else (call echo %%f%% %%b%% not 13th)"
```

**Output** (two files in current directory):

```
==> D:\bat\SO\34475095.bat

14.09.201522:36:05 : 13th
27.12.201501:09:47 : 13th

14.09.201522:36:05 : 13th
27.12.201501:09:47 : 13th

14.09.201522:36:05 : 13th
27.12.201501:09:47 : 13th

==>
```

**Hint** for long file names: keep in mind that e.g. `@Path` variable includes surrounding `"` double quotes already; use surrounding `"` double quotes [escaped](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) as `\"` instead common `""` or `^"` for custom filename parts; for instance,

```
… if [!b!]==[:] (echo(!f! \"!b! 13th\") else (echo(!f! \"!b! not 13th\")
```

would display

```
14.09.201522:36:05 ": 13th"
27.12.201501:09:47 ": 13th"
```

Comment: When i put
`… /C "cmd /V:ON /c set "f=@fdate@ftime" & set "b=!f:~12,1!" & echo !b!"`
into cmd, i get smth like

`2

3

:

:

7

:`

which is right

Comment: I had problems with commenting, sorry

When i put
`… /C "cmd /V:ON /c set "f=@fdate@ftime" & set "b=!f:~12,1!" & echo !b!"`
into cmd, i get smth like

`2

3

:

:

7

:`

which is right, but when i put

`… /C "cmd /c set "f=@fdate@ftime" & call set "b=%%f:~12,1%%" & call set "b=%%b::=%%" & if not defined b (call "foo")"`

i get nothing. Same for 2nd solution. Can u help?

Comment: I made a mistake, "but when i put 

`… /C "cmd /V:ON /c set "f=@fdate@ftime" & set "b=!f:~12,1!" & if [!b!]==[:] (call "foo")"`

i get nothing`

Comment: One more thing. How can i add space in rename? Instead of `_`
`rename @file !f:~6,4!.!f:~3,2!.!f:~0,2!_[!f:~10,2!-!f:~13,2!-!f:~16,2!`

Comment: Instead of escaped `"` in `forfiles` like `\"`, I strongly recommed the alternative method to use the quote's hex. code `0x22`, because the escaped quotes are considered escaped _only_ for `forfiles` but _not_ for the `cmd` instance it is running in, which might be confused by the quotes; `0x22` however does not have any special meaning for `cmd` at all...